# Basic Neo4J Match query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use the [POLE dataset](https://github.com/neo4j-graph-examples/pole) and list a few things but I am struggling to graph the outputs that I want and im just a bit confused on the documention.

I want to list all the crimes committed at "27 Maiden Close" as well as the Crimes listed at piccadilly and the count of those crimes.

Comment: please share to us what you have tried and also tell use what is the error. Also, please share the location of "POLE" dataset. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jose. You can check it here https://github.com/neo4j-graph-examples/pole. And this is how I solve it `match(n:Crime)
where n.location = "27 Maiden Close” or n.location = “piccadilly”
return collect(n) as crimes, count(*) as cnt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
MATCH (c:Crime)-[:OCCURRED_AT]->(l:Location) WHERE l.address IN ['27 Maiden Close','Piccadilly'] 
WITH collect({crime_id:c.id,crime_type:c.type,crime_last_outcome:c.last_outcome}) as crimes,l,count(c.id) as crimesCount
RETURN crimes,crimesCount,l.address
```

Or this?

```
MATCH (c:Crime)-[:OCCURRED_AT]->(l:Location) WHERE l.address IN ['27 Maiden Close','Piccadilly'] 
WITH collect({id:c.id,type:c.type,last_outcome:c.last_outcome}) as crimes,l,count(c.id) as crimesCount
UNWIND crimes as crime
RETURN crime.id,crime.type,crime.last_outcome,crimesCount,l.address
```

Comment: Thanks, Luis. I have solved it Like this `match(n:Crime)
where n.location = "27 Maiden Close” or n.location = “piccadilly”
return collect(n) as crimes, count(*) as cnt` as I wanted to return the count and collect

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by using:
`match(n:Crime) where n.location = "27 Maiden Close” or n.location = “piccadilly” return collect(n) as crimes, count(*) as cnt`